# How to preprocess and load a "big data" tsv file into a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, awk, sed, dataframe

I am currently trying to import the following large tab-delimited file into a dataframe-like structure within Python---naturally I am using `pandas` dataframe, though I am open to other options.

This file is several GB in size, and is not a standard `tsv` file---it is broken, i.e. the rows have a different number of columns. One row may have 25 columns, another has 21.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Col_01: 14 .... Col_20: 25    Col_21: 23432    Col_22: 639142
Col_01: 8  .... Col_20: 25    Col_22: 25134    Col_23: 243344
Col_01: 17 .... Col_21: 75    Col_23: 79876    Col_25: 634534    Col_22: 5    Col_24: 73453
Col_01: 19 .... Col_20: 25    Col_21: 32425    Col_23: 989423
Col_01: 12 .... Col_20: 25    Col_21: 23424    Col_22: 342421    Col_23: 7    Col_24: 13424    Col_25: 67
Col_01: 3  .... Col_20: 95    Col_21: 32121    Col_25: 111231
```

As you can see, some of these columns are not in the correct order...

Now, I think the correct way to import this file into a dataframe is to preprocess the data such that you can output a dataframe with `NaN` values, e.g.

```
Col_01 .... Col_20    Col_21    Col22    Col23    Col24    Col25
8      .... 25        NaN       25134    243344   NaN      NaN
17     .... NaN       75        2        79876    73453    634534
19     .... 25        32425     NaN      989423   NaN      NaN
12     .... 25        23424     342421   7        13424    67
3      .... 95        32121     NaN      NaN      NaN      111231
```

To make this even more complicated, this is a very large file, several GB in size.

Normally, I try to process the data in chunks, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

for chunk in pd.read_table(FILE_PATH, header=None, sep='\t', chunksize=10**6):
    # place chunks into a dataframe or HDF
```

However, I see no way to "preprocess" the data first in chunks, and then use chunks to read the data into `pandas.read_table()`. How would you do this? What sort of preprocessing tools are available---perhaps `sed`? `awk`?

This is a challenging problem, due to the size of the data and the formatting that must be done before loading into a dataframe. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the "maximal" (the most complete one - i.e. which includes all possible column names) list of column names beforehand?

Comment: @MaxU An extensive list of all column names used? Yes, I think so

Comment: Not sure if I have understood the problem correctly, but we had a similar problem with "dirty" file and we used R to cleanup the data and then pass the new file to Spark for further processing.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, so for this sample data set it would be a list of columns: `Col_01` ... `Col_25`. But can you generate such an __ordered__ list of columns for your real data?

Comment: Here is a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331907/how-to-find-and-print-specific-character-in-bash/39349817#39349817 Remove the alphabet creating for loop and use a column header as described in the end of post.

Comment: @JamesBrown, it looks very promising (+1)! Can you provide a working AWK solution for this particular case - it might be helpful for the Pandas community, because not all of us have your level of expertise in AWK... ;)

Comment: I probably should, it's the 3rd time in 2 days it's needed. Gimme a sec, it's almost midnight here.

Comment: @MaxU How does the below answer accomplish `for chunk in pd.read_table(FILE_PATH, header=None, sep='\t', chunksize=10**6):`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, what do you mean? After preprocessing your data you can simply read it in chunks (but i would use `sep='\s+'` instead)

Comment: @MaxU So, store the entire output of the awk file, and then read from that in chunks? Save it how (it's +GB)? Or somehow call awk through Python via Subprocess? e.g. `result = subprocess.check_output(["awk ","-F","pandas.awk", "cols.txt",chunk])`? In this case, awk would have to be written to take in a line as input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870135/how-to-process-and-save-data-in-chunks-using-awk

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, basically you should do the following in the UNIX shell: `awk -F pandas.awk cols.txt pandas.txt > file.csv` and after that you can process `file.csv` with pandas in Python

Comment: @MaxU This solutions means saving two +GB files to disk, then writing the contents into a HDF5 format. There's no way to have awk parse lines and then save those lines into HDF5 format, rather than save 3 large files?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, what are your constraints? Processing speed, RAM, disk space?

Comment: @MaxU DiskSpace isn't a problem. RAM could be. The issue is I actually do not have a `pandas.txt` file, but rather output from third-party software which parses a file, outputting tab-delimited text data. You run in the command line `commericalsoftware execute file` and this outputs tab-delimited text. This is what I have been trying to use a pipe, or parse the data line by line. Perhaps `commericalsoftware execute file |  awk -F pandas.awk cols.txt > file.csv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat > pandas.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" # traversal order for for(i in a)                  
}
NR==1 {       # the header cols is in the beginning of data file
              # FORGET THIS: header cols from another file replace NR==1 with NR==FNR and see * below
    split($0,a," ")                  # mkheader a[1]=first_col ...
    for(i in a) {                    # replace with a[first_col]="" ...
        a[a[i]]
        printf "%6s%s", a[i], OFS    # output the header
        delete a[i]                  # remove a[1], a[2], ...
    }
    # next                           # FORGET THIS * next here if cols from another file UNTESTED
}
{
    gsub(/: /,"=")                   # replace key-value separator ": " with "="
    split($0,b,FS)                   # split record from ","
    for(i in b) {
        split(b[i],c,"=")            # split key=value to c[1]=key, c[2]=value
        b[c[1]]=c[2]                 # b[key]=value
    }
    for(i in a)                      # go thru headers in a[] and printf from b[]
        printf "%6s%s", (i in b?b[i]:"NaN"), OFS; print ""
}
```

Data sample (`pandas.txt`):

```
Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25
Col_01: 14  Col_20: 25    Col_21: 23432    Col_22: 639142
Col_01: 8   Col_20: 25    Col_22: 25134    Col_23: 243344
Col_01: 17  Col_21: 75    Col_23: 79876    Col_25: 634534    Col_22: 5    Col_24: 73453
Col_01: 19  Col_20: 25    Col_21: 32425    Col_23: 989423
Col_01: 12  Col_20: 25    Col_21: 23424    Col_22: 342421    Col_23: 7    Col_24: 13424    Col_25: 67
Col_01: 3   Col_20: 95    Col_21: 32121    Col_25: 111231

$ awk -f pandas.awk -pandas.txt
Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25
    14     25  23432 639142    NaN    NaN 
     8     25    NaN  25134 243344    NaN 
    17    NaN     75      5  79876 634534 
    19     25  32425    NaN 989423    NaN 
    12     25  23424 342421      7     67 
     3     95  32121    NaN    NaN 111231
```

All needed cols should be in the data file header. It's probably not a big job to collect the headers while processing, just keep the data in arrays and print in the end, maybe in version 3.

If you read the headers from a different file (`cols.txt`) than the data file (`pandas.txt`), execute the script (`pandas.awk`):

```
$ awk -F pandas.awk cols.txt pandas.txt
```

Comment: It's a great solution, thank you! What would be the most `AWK-ish` way to read the header line `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25` from different file?

Comment: Probably replace the `NR==1` with `FNR==NR` and end the following block with `{... next}`. See comments in code.

Comment: AND: run it with: `awk -F pandas.awk cols.txt pandas.txt`. Column headers in file `cols.txt` need to be space separated.

Comment: ... and like you can see in the `pandas.txt` header, forgotten `Col_24` does not get outputed...

Comment: Good night. I'll comment it out tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My awk is rusty: Is it possible to exclude/include certain columns before parsing it into a pandas data frame? For example, we only want columns `Col1`,  `Col2`,  `Col3`,  `Col4`, etc.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang What is in the header gets outputed (IIRC). Edit: Yeah, I tested it, only what is in the header gets outputed.

Comment: @JamesBrown Using the example above, let's say instead of `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25`, we're restricted to `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21`

Comment: Replace the header line with `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21` and try. The headers must be in ascending order, though. I'll try to fix it one day.

Comment: @JamesBrown Could you expand on this "It's probably not a big job to collect the headers while processing, just keep the data in arrays and print in the end"? You would somehow parse the columns at the end and then reuse them at the beginning?

Comment: Yeah, make two runs on the same file, collect all elements on the first run and build the header for the second, actual run. It's possible. How big are the files usually? Is such feature usable?

Comment: Such a feature is *very* useful. Also, currently get an error: `cols.txt` is just a line `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25`
This is the error I get running `$ awk -F pandas.awk cols.txt pandas.txt`:
`awk: syntax error at source line 1`
`context is`
 ` >>> cols. <<< txt`
`awk: bailing out at source line 1`

Comment: What if I simply supply a string `Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25` as a flag?

Comment: Works just fine for me. Which setup do you have? I'm on Linux, usin Gnu awk. What do you mean by _as a flag_? Any you don't have to edit the code at all to use the cols from a different file, btw.

Comment: @MaxU @JamesBrown Just to clarify, I'm still not entirely sure how this awk solution is used to put the lines into a dataframe, i.e. `for line in read_file(): # place line/chunk in dataframe, e.g. df=pd.concat([df, line])`
The way we run awk, it appears that the entire file will be parsed---how do save the parsed output as "chunks"?

Comment: @MaxU @JamesBrown There may be a way to use ` printf "%6s%s", (i in b?b[i]:"NaN"), OFS; print ""` as the "chunk" or line in the example above, and then iterate over the entire file? How do I take one line/chunk of awk output and save into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @JamesBrown I've started another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870135/how-to-process-and-save-data-in-chunks-using-awk?noredirect=1#comment67028040_39870135

Answer (score 3):

Another version which takes a separate column file as parameter or uses the first record. Run either way:

```
awk -f pandas2.awk pandas.txt # first record as header
awk -f pandas2.awk cols.txt pandas.txt # first record from cols.txt
awk -v cols="cols.txt" -f pandas2.awk pandas.txt # read cols from cols.txt
```

Or even:

```
awk -v cols="pandas.txt" -f pandas2.awk pandas.txt # separates keys from pandas.txt for header
```

Code:

```
$ cat > pandas2.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" # traversal order for for(i in a)
    if(cols) {                           # if -v cols="column_file.txt" or even "pandas.txt"
        while ((getline line< cols)>0) { # read it in line by line
            gsub(/: [^ ]+/,"",line)      # remove values from "key: value"
            split(line,a)                # split to temp array
            for(i in a)                  # collect keys to column array
                col[a[i]]
        }
        for(i in col)                    # output columns
            printf "%6s%s", i, OFS
        print ""
    }
}
NR==1 && cols=="" {                      # if the header cols are in the beginning of data file
                                         # if not, -v cols="column_file.txt"
    split($0,a," +")                     # split header record by spaces
    for(i in a) {
        col[a[i]]                        # set them to array col
        printf "%6s%s", a[i], OFS        # output the header
    }
    print ""
}
NR==1 {
    next
}
{
    gsub(/: /,"=")                       # replace key-value separator ": " with "="
    split($0,b,FS)                       # split record from separator FS
    for(i in b) {
        split(b[i],c,"=")                # split key=value to c[1]=key, c[2]=value
        b[c[1]]=c[2]                     # b[key]=value
    }
    for(i in col)                        # go thru headers in col[] and printf from b[]
        printf "%6s%s", (i in b?b[i]:"NaN"), OFS; print ""
}
```

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Version 2, check it out.

Comment: Sorry for the unbelievable delay---really want to thank you for this! I was confused previously regarding how the header line was processed. This has been a great way to learn awk!

Comment: Your superpowers might be useful here :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/39516975#39516975

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more cleanly completely in Pandas.

Suppose you have two independent data frames with only one overlapping column:

```
>>> df1
   A  B
0  1  2
>>> df2
   B  C
1  3  4
```

You can use [.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) to concatenate them together:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2])
    A  B   C
0   1  2 NaN
1 NaN  3   4
```

You can see `NaN` is created for row values that do not exist.

This can easily be applied to your example data without preprocessing at all:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
with open(fn) as f_in:
    for i, line in enumerate(f_in):
        line_data=pd.DataFrame({k.strip():v.strip() 
                  for k,_,v in (e.partition(':') 
                        for e in line.split('\t'))}, index=[i])
        df=pd.concat([df, line_data])

>>> df
  Col_01 Col_20 Col_21  Col_22  Col_23 Col_24  Col_25
0     14     25  23432  639142     NaN    NaN     NaN
1      8     25    NaN   25134  243344    NaN     NaN
2     17    NaN     75       5   79876  73453  634534
3     19     25  32425     NaN  989423    NaN     NaN
4     12     25  23424  342421       7  13424      67
5      3     95  32121     NaN     NaN    NaN  111231
```

---

Alternatively, if your main issue is establishing the desired order of the columns in a multi chunk add of columns, just read all the column value first (not tested):

```
# based on the alpha numeric sort of the example of:
# [ALPHA]_[NUM]
headers=set()
with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
        for record in line.split('\t'):
            head,_,datum=record.partition(":")
            headers.add(head)
# sort as you wish:             
cols=sorted(headers, key=lambda e: int(e.partition('_')[2]))
```

Pandas will use the order of the list for the column order if given in the initial creation of the DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for this. The last line wouldn't work though given the problem---let's assume we have a file 1T in size and we storing this in an HDF5 file to disk. We won't be able to hold `df=pd.concat[df, line_data])` into RAM. After parsing the data, we use  `for line in pd.table(): store("HDF5").append(line)` and then afterwards save via `store.create_table()` See my discussion of "chunks" above.

Comment: However, I think you might be able to use `line_data` as the chunk and then proceed as you normally would saving to an HDF5. Could you explain how this deals with (1) rows of unequal number of fields and (2) fields in the wrong order? (e.g. first row has columns 1, 24, 22, 21, the next row has 1, 21, 22, 23, etc.)

Comment: The column order is based on an alpha numeric sort order after the set index operation of adding new columns. In this particular case, with your example data, works great. If the order of the columns is not what is desired, you can change it at the end with `df=df[desired_order]`

Comment: So, I've been trying the above code, but the input file is 'binary'. Um, any ideas? I've been trying options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861431/how-to-decode-binary-file-with-for-index-line-in-enumeratefile/39861533#39861533

Comment: What kind of binary? You need to know about the file format. Is it just `utf-8` or some other form of encoding? If so, use the correct decoder as you open the file and a logically correct stream will be presented to you.

Comment: All I know it's a tab-delimited file format that was been compressed and made binary. So, perhaps this is a special format/encoding release by this software. Users are encouraged to use their software via the command line to open the file in standard TAB-delimited text file with `softwarecommand view filename`
Given these command line tools, perhaps I could open the file line by line with Python subprocess? https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: If you can open and decompress at the command line, do that. You can either use subprocess or write a filter: `softwarecommand view filename | your_python_program_that_reads_stdin`

Comment: How would you write something like `your_python_program_that_reads_stdin`?  Resources/suggestions? 

My idea would be to open and decompress at the command line with their tools (because this is a strange format, perhaps encrypted) and then use your code `with open(fn) as f_in:    for i, line in enumerate(f_in): line_data=pd.DataFrame({k.strip():v.strip() ....`

Comment: Use the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module. A trivial example `$ seq 10 | python -c 'import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(): print line.strip()'`

Comment: So, `softwarecommand view filename` just outputs lines upon lines of TAB-delimited text in the command line. How does fileinput work as a filter? Not sure I follow

Comment: do you mean `softwarecommand view filename | python script.py` where `script.py` parses the output, e.g. `for line in sys.stdin: ...`?

Comment: Yes -- exactly. In that case, `python script.py` is acting as a filter because you would commonly have `something_producing_lines | filter_reading_lines > result_of_processing_lines` Clear?

Comment: Sorry, one (hopefully) last question: previously, we were using `for i, line in enumerate(f_in):..., index=[i])`. Now, we are doing this by line, i.e. `for line in  fileinput.input()`. But I think we still need an index. Without it, I get a ValueError, i.e. `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`
Using fileinput, could you maybe count each line as the index? Thanks for continued help

Comment: Yes -- you can use `enumerate` on `fileinput.input()` the same as if it were a text file.

Comment: Update: So, using`enumerate` on `sys.stdin` instead results in a few rows being written, but then I get this error `ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for...`

Comment: So, this seems to be a common HDF5 error. It's possible this is because after two rows, the DataFrame object has "sniffed" the table structure and decided that there's parsing issues?

Comment: Actually, the error is from here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/1894419/

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this with chunks, i.e. How does the below answer accomplish `for chunk in pd.read_table(FILE_PATH, header=None, sep='\t', chunksize=10**6):`?

Comment: What if `df=pd.concat([df, line_data])` is bigger than RAM?