# Split column and use first array to headerin awk

Tags: bash, awk, split, header

I have file looks like this:

```
A=10 B=8 C=12
A=15 B=12 C=5
A=6 B=4 C=9
A=8 B=8 C=9
```

Columns are much more. I would like to split all file using awk and use letter before "=" like a header:

```
A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

I would like to do something like:

```
awk '{split($0,arr0,"="); print arr0[2]}' infile
```

But still do not know how to use `arr0[1]` like header.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Here is one, just change the `: ` delimiter to `=`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/39399727#39399727

Comment: @JamesBrown yeah I did not found this solution before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F '[= ]' 'function prnt(start) {
   for (i=start; i<=NF; i+=2)
      printf "%s%s", (i==start?"":OFS), $i
   print ""
}
NR==1 {
   prnt(1)
}
{
   prnt(2)
}' file

A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

And to get tabular formatted output use:

```
awk -F '[= ]' 'function prnt(start) {
   for (i=start; i<=NF; i+=2)
      printf "%s%s", (i==start?"":OFS), $i
   print ""
}
NR==1 {
   prnt(1)
}
{
   prnt(2)
}' file | column -t

A   B   C
10  8   12
15  12  5
6   4   9
8   8   9
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0;gsub(/=[^ ]+/,"",h);print h} {gsub(/[^ =]+=/,"")} 1' file
A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed '1{h;s/=[^ ]*//g;p;x};s/.=//g' file

A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

with `perl`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
A=10 B=8 C=12
A=15 B=12 C=5
A=6 B=4 C=9
A=8 B=8 C=9

$ # can also use: perl -lpe 'print / ?[^ ]+(?==)/g if $.==1; s/[^ ]+=//g'
$ perl -pe 'if($. == 1){$a = s/=[^ ]+//rg; print "$a\n"} s/[^ ]+=//g' ip.txt
A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

- `if($. == 1){$a = s/=[^ ]+//rg; print "$a\n"}` for first line, delete `=` and non-space characters to its right. The substitution result is saved in `$a` and printed without modifying input line
- `s/[^ ]+=//g` delete non-space characters followed by `=` for all lines
- `-p` option means input line gets printed after all the modifications by default

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/awk

function print_record( hdr )
{
    for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
    {
        split( $i, a, "=" )
        printf a[ ( hdr == 1 ) ? 1 : 2 ] " "
    }

    print ""
}

BEGIN {
    hdr=1
}

{
    if( hdr == 1 )
    {
        print_record( 1 )
        hdr = 0;
    }

    print_record( 0 )
}

# eof #
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt
```

Output:

```
A B C 
10 8 12 
15 12 5 
6 4 9 
8 8 9
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Gnu awk:

```
split($0,a,"[ =]") && NR==1 {   # split the record from <space> and "="
    print a[1],a[3],a[5]        # first record, print odds
    # for(i=1;i<=NF*2;i+=2)     # you could replace above print with this
    #    printf "%s", a[i] OFS; print ""
}
{
    print a[3],a[4],a[6]        # the rest of records, print evens
    # for(i=2;i<=NF*2;i+=2)     # you could replace above print with this
    #     printf "%s", a[i] OFS; print ""
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk foo.awk foo.txt
A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lean, `awk` implementation:

```
BEGIN{
  print "A", "B", "C";
}

{
  split($1, a, /=/);
  split($2, b, /=/);
  split($3, c, /=/);

  print a[2], b[2], c[2];
}
```

...and the output:

```
$ awk -f /tmp/script.awk </tmp/input
A B C
10 8 12
15 12 5
6 4 9
8 8 9
```