# How to decode binary file with " for index, line in enumerate(file)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decode, enumerate

I am opening up an extremely large binary file I am opening in Python 3.5 in `file1.py`:

```
with open(pathname, 'rb') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        # parsing here
```

However, I naturally get an error because I am reading the file in binary mode and then creating a list of bytes. Then with a for loop, you are comparing string to bytes and here the code fails.

If I was reading in individual lines, I would do this:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    lines = [x.decode('utf8').strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

However, I am using `for index, lines in enumerate(file):`. What is the correct approach in this case? Do I decode the next objects?

Here is the actual code I am running:

```
with open(bam_path, 'rb') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        line_data=pd.DataFrame({k.strip():v.strip()
            for k,_,v in (e.partition(':')
                for e in line.split('\t'))}, index=[i])
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                
  File "file1.py", line 18, in <module>                                                                                        
    for e in line.split('\t'))}, index=[i])                                                                                       
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Why do you expect a binary file to have lines?

Comment: @matthias It's a Tab-delimited text format compressed in binary. How would you open the above? It is a huge file, 500 GB or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could feed a generator with the decoded lines to `enumerate`:

```
for i, line in enumerate(l.decode(errors='ignore') for l in f):
```

Which does the trick of yielding every line in `f` after decoding it. I've added `errors='ignore'` due to the fact that opening with `r` failed with an unknown start byte.

As an aside, you could just replace all string literals with byte literals when operating on `bytes`, i.e: `partition(b':')`, `split(b'\t')` and do your work using `bytes` (pretty sure pandas works fine with them).

Comment: The file is orginally a huge (~500 GB) tab-delimited text file, which is now in binary. How would you open this?

Comment: Trying to open only with `r` gives this error: File "bam_file.py", line 15, in <module>
    for i, line in enumerate(l.decode() for l in file):
  File "bam_file.py", line 15, in <genexpr>
    for i, line in enumerate(l.decode() for l in file):
  File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: I see, a part of the input string can't be converted apparently. I'd go with `l.decode(errors='ignore') for l in f` for opening the file. Supplying a generator also assures that the contents won't all be loaded in memory.

Comment: Here's the error I get with `l.decode(errors='ignore')`
:File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: and you opened the file with `rb` again?

Comment: No, I am using `r`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Change the opening to `'rb`' and use `enumerate(l.decode(errors='ignore') for l in f)`.