# How to process and save data in chunks using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, dataframe

Let's say I'm opening a large (several GB) file where I cannot read in the entire file as once.

If it's a csv file, we would use:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('path/filename', chunksize=10**7):
    # save chunk to disk
```

Or we could do something similar with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
with open(fn) as file:
    for line in file:
        # save line to disk, e.g. df=pd.concat([df, line_data]), then save the df
```

How does one "chunk" data with an awk script? Awk will parse/process text into a format you desire, but I don't know how to "chunk" with awk. One can write a script `script1.awk` and then process your data, but this processes the entire file at once.

Related question, with more concrete example: [How to preprocess and load a "big data" tsv file into a python dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/)

Comment: Are you asking if `awk` can split a big file to multiple ones based on a condition? If so, _yes_ it is possible. It would be more helpul if you provide some more information like your input file and how would you like to process it

Comment: doesn't awk read line by line by default (can be changed using RS to specify different record separator) - thus file size is moot?

Comment: what is the question about? awk or python/pandas? If you're already using python I don't see the point using awk.

Comment: @Inian I understand, but I don't want to repeat the well-documented question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/

Comment: @Sundeep Then how do you save each line, line by line, into (say) a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre See discussion, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, as Inian pointed out, can you add a sample input (say 5 lines) with expected output? that would help to clarify

Comment: @Sundeep I think these are shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/
The question I now have is, instead of using an awk script to process the entire input file `pandas.txt` (for the example in the link) all at once, how does one process the file line by line, i.e. take a line in the file, use awk, then save this line, repeat.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang That's how awk processes files also, if not programmed against it, ie. awk processes a record (line) of data and prints it out or if needed, data is read, processed and stored in memory and printed out in a separate `END{}` block (in a nutshell). If you would like something to happen after a line is processed, you add that to the awk program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk reads a single record *(chunk)* at a time by design. By default a record is line of data, but you can specify a record using the `RS` *(record separator)* variable. Each code block is conditionally executed on the current record before the next is read:

```
$ awk '/pattern/{print "MATCHED", $0 > "output"}' file
```

The above script will read a line at a time from the input file and if the that line matchs `pattern` it will save the line in the file output prepended with `MATCHED` before reading the next line.

Comment: Please take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886440/python-subprocess-command-requires-a-text-file-to-read-but-takes-lines-from-tex
In Python, I could take a line `line` and save it into an HDF5 file format. I cannot do this with awk, can I?