# Can we use AWK and gsub() to process data with multiple colons ":" ? How?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gsub

Here is an example of the data:

```
Col_01:14 .... Col_20:25    Col_21:23432    Col_22:639142
Col_01:8  .... Col_20:25    Col_22:25134    Col_23:243344
Col_01:17 .... Col_21:75    Col_23:79876    Col_25:634534    Col_22:5    Col_24:73453
Col_01:19 .... Col_20:25    Col_21:32425    Col_23:989423
Col_01:12 .... Col_20:25    Col_21:23424    Col_22:342421    Col_23:7    Col_24:13424    Col_25:67
Col_01:3  .... Col_20:95    Col_21:32121    Col_25:111231
```

As you can see, some of these columns are not in the correct order...

Now, I think the correct way to import this file into a dataframe is to preprocess the data such that you can output a dataframe with `NaN` values, e.g.

```
Col_01 .... Col_20    Col_21    Col22    Col23    Col24    Col25
8      .... 25        NaN       25134    243344   NaN      NaN
17     .... NaN       75        2        79876    73453    634534
19     .... 25        32425     NaN      989423   NaN      NaN
12     .... 25        23424     342421   7        13424    67
3      .... 95        32121     NaN      NaN      NaN      111231
```

The solution was shown by @JamesBrown here : [How to preprocess and load a "big data" tsv file into a python dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/)

Using said awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" # traversal order for for(i in a)                  
}
NR==1 {       # the header cols is in the beginning of data file
              # FORGET THIS: header cols from another file replace NR==1 with NR==FNR and see * below
    split($0,a," ")                  # mkheader a[1]=first_col ...
    for(i in a) {                    # replace with a[first_col]="" ...
        a[a[i]]
        printf "%6s%s", a[i], OFS    # output the header
        delete a[i]                  # remove a[1], a[2], ...
    }
    # next                           # FORGET THIS * next here if cols from another file UNTESTED
}
{
    gsub(/: /,"=")                   # replace key-value separator ": " with "="
    split($0,b,FS)                   # split record from ","
    for(i in b) {
        split(b[i],c,"=")            # split key=value to c[1]=key, c[2]=value
        b[c[1]]=c[2]                 # b[key]=value
    }
    for(i in a)                      # go thru headers in a[] and printf from b[]
        printf "%6s%s", (i in b?b[i]:"NaN"), OFS; print ""
}
```

And put the headers into a text file `cols.txt`

```
Col_01 Col_20 Col_21 Col_22 Col_23 Col_25
```

My question now: how do we use awk if we have data that is not `column: value` but `column: value1: value2: value3`?

We would want the database entry to be `value1: value2: value3`

Here's the new data:

```
Col_01:14:a:47 .... Col_20:25:i:z    Col_21:23432:6:b    Col_22:639142:4:x
Col_01:8:z .... Col_20:25:i:4    Col_22:25134:u:0    Col_23:243344:5:6
Col_01:17:7:z .... Col_21:75:u:q    Col_23:79876:u:0    Col_25:634534:8:1
```

We still provide the columns beforehand with `cols.txt`

How can we create a similar database structure? Is it possible to use `gsub()` to limit to the first value before `:` which is the same as the header?

EDIT: This doesn't *have to* be awk based. Any language will do naturally

Comment: @JamesBrown I mentioned your expertise above. Thank you again!

Comment: it may be easier if you can rebuild your original data with an different char for the extended values. Maybe `@` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'm not following your logic---what do you mean? Parse through each of the values individually?

Comment: Can you rely on the column names beginning with "Col_" ?

Comment: A program is creating your data file. Change it so instead of  outputting (for example) `Col_23: 79876:u:0` it will output `Col_23:78976@u@0`. Then you can easily use `split(fld,fldArr,":");split(FldArr[2],valArr,"@")`. Good Luck.

Comment: @glennjackman For this example, yes. In actuality, the column names are unique names. However, we know their identity and we know that every line will have them.

Comment: @shelter What if the extended values had a certain pattern? That is, the intermediate value was always either A or Z, e.g. there were either `Col_1:A:##` or `Col_3:Z:##`

Comment: Next question:the col1 value on the 2nd line. Of the new data does not have format `valeu1:value2:valeu3`. Is this a typo or lifelike data?

Comment: @glennjackman Do you mean `Col_01: 8: z`? That's a typo. There are no spaces in between colons. Lifelike data is more like "all fields Col1 will have the format `Col1:string:number`, where string begins with H. Col22 will always have the format `Col22:##:A:##`, where it's always the letter A. The rest might be `field_value:number`, a key-value pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another alternative...

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)                  # iterate over name: value pairs
                     {c=$i;                             # copy name in c to modify
                      sub(/:/,"",c);                    # remove colon
                      a[NR,c]=$(i+1);                   # collect data by row number, name
                      cols[c]}}                         # save name
                END{n=asorti(cols,icols);               # sort names
                    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) printf "%s", icols[j] OFS;   # print header 
                    print ""; 
                    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)                  # print data
                      {for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                         {v=a[i,icols[j]];             
                          printf "%s", (v?v:"NaN") OFS} # replace missing data with NaN
                       print ""}}' file | column -t     # pipe to column for pretty print

Col_01   Col_20  Col_21     Col_22      Col_23      Col_25
14:a:47  25:i:z  23432:6:b  639142:4:x  NaN         NaN
8:z      25:i:4  NaN        25134:u:0   243344:5:6  NaN
17:7:z   NaN     75:u:q     NaN         79876:u:0   634534:8:1
```

Comment: Thank you for this! At the risk of misunderstanding: `-v` defined the OFS variable to be a tab-delimiter, and the variable `file` and `column` is the pathname to the file and `columns.txt` file respectively? Where do you defines 'cols'?

Comment: `-v` is to define `awk` variables, this sets OFS as you figured out.  `file` is your input file, and `column -t` is pretty formatting output, which you can ignore. `cols` is defined with `cols[c]`, when added the first element `c`, similar to data array `a`.

Comment: So, for an input file with a varying number of fields per row (like in the above example, e.g. Col_25 does not appear until the third row), this will keep tracking of all unique column values, overcoming the "sniffer" function for more file input functions.

Comment: yes, we collect the names in `cols` array to refer later.

Comment: This works great, except for a sloppy error on my part discussed below. There are no spaces between any fields, e.g. `Col_01:14:a:47` is correct, not `Col_01: 14:a:47`, so there are some columns that are out of whack during my test. This is my fault, as that's what the data above shows. What would be the corrections to the above?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask this. However, I actually have never run an AWK without a BEGIN. I can run this in the command line, but how do you convert this into a script? I'm following the line spacing above and running with `awk  -v OFS='\t' -f script.awk file`, but there are annoying line source errors. (Sorry for bothering you with this...)

Comment: copy the contents between single quotes (excluding the quotes) into script.awk file.  Line spacing is not important since I used `;` as expression delimiters.

Comment: Found the error---sorry, I was worried I had made mistake. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

I had karakfa's answer as well. If the column name is not separated by whitespace from the value (e.g. if you have `Col_01:14:a:47`) then you can do this (using GNU awk for the extended `match` function)

```
  {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
          match($i, /^([^:]+):(.*)/, m)
          a[NR,m[1]] = m[2]
          cols[m[1]]
     }
  }
```

The END block is the same

Comment: Thank you for this! Very n00b question: I would expect `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)`, but @karakfa uses `i+=2`. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: His answer parses the file where you have `Col_01: 14:a:47` (with a space, thus counts as separate fields in awk). This one will parse a file where you have `Col_01:14:a:47` (without a space)

Comment: @glennjackson I understand now. Yes, this was sloppy on my part. Thank you! And both of you are defining `cols` via `columns.txt`? So you must be executing the above script  like `awk  awk -v OFS='\t'  script.awk | cols.txt -t`

Comment: You need to be more precise when you show us what your data really is. As you can see, it's crucially important.

Comment: Not just awk, any text parsing regardless of the tool.

Comment: Is it possible to create a solution that works on lines within the file instead of a file itself? So, the lines are tab-delimited text, which I'm outputting in chunks/rows. `awk -v OFS='\t' -f script.awk file` works (though doesn't scale). `awk -v OFS='\t' -f script.awk line` where `line` is `for line in file:` fails. 
Otherwise, my only recourse at the moment seems to be to save the lines into a text file, run awk, and then discard.

Comment: You can use awk like a filter: `some_process | awk -v OFS="\t" -f script awk`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow---I think it still needs a text file as input; input cannot be readlines from the text file---perhaps there's a to use a string, run through awk, and then take the output----I realize this isn't efficient of course, but how would lines be read? By a filter, you mean pass lines continuously and pipe into awk? I think I'm trying that

Answer (score 1):

Using [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr)'s Lisp [macro implementation](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC) of the Awk paradigm:

```lisp
(awk (:set ft #/-?\d+/)  ;; ft is "field tokenize" (no counterpart in Awk)
     (:let (tab (hash :equal-based)) (max-col 1) (width 8))
     ((ff (mapcar toint) (tuples 2))  ;; filter fields to int and shore up into pairs
      (set max-col (max max-col [find-max [mapcar first f]]))
      (mapdo (ado set [tab ^(,nr ,@1)] @2) f)) ;; stuff data into table
     (:end (let ((headings (mapcar (opip (format nil "Col~,02a")
                                         `@{@1 width}`)
                                   (range 1 max-col))))
             (put-line `@{headings " "}`))
           (each ((row (range 1 nr)))
             (let ((cols (mapcar (opip (or [tab ^(,row ,@1)] "NaN")
                                       `@{@1 width}`)
                                 (range 1 max-col))))
               (put-line `@{cols " "}`)))))
```

Smaller sample data:

```
Col_01: 14  Col_04: 25    Col_06: 23432    Col_07: 639142
Col_02: 8   Col_03: 25    Col_05: 25134    Col_06: 243344
Col_01: 17
Col_06: 19  Col_07: 32425
```

Run:

```
$ txr reformat.tl data-small
Col01    Col02    Col03    Col04    Col05    Col06    Col07
14       NaN      NaN      25       NaN      23432    639142
NaN      8        25       NaN      25134    243344   NaN
17       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      19       32425
```

---

P.S. [`opip`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01937C5A) is a macro which boostraps from the [`op`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0068EA9D) macro for partial function applications; `opip` implicitly distributes `op` into its argument expressions, and then chains the resulting functions together into a functional pipeline: hence "`op`-pipe". In each pipeline element, its own numbered implicit arguments can be referenced: `@1`, `@2`, ... if they are absent, then the partially applied function implicitly receives the piped object as its rightmost argument.

The `^(,row ,@1)` syntax is TXR Lisp's backquote. The backtick that mainstream Lisp dialects use for backquote is already employed for string quasiquotes. This is equivalent to `(list row @1)`: make a list consisting of the value of  `row` and of the implicit, `op/do`-generated function argument `@1`.  Lists of two elements are being used as the hash keys, which simulates a 2D array. For that, the hash must be `:equal-based`. The lists `(1 2)` `(1 2)` are not `eql` if they are separate instances rather than one and the same object; they compare equal under the `equal` function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, some incomprehensible perl

```
perl -aE'%l=%{{@F}};while(($k,$v)=each%l){$c{$k}=1;$a[$.]{$k}=$v}END{$,="\t";say@c=sort keys%c;for$i(1..$.){say map{$a[$i]{$_}//"NaN"}@c}}' input
```

(community wiki to hide my shame ...)

Golfed a few chars:

```
perl -aE'while(@F){$c{$k=shift@F}=1;$data[$.]{$k}=shift@F}END{$,="\t";say@c=sort keys%c;for$i(1..$.){say map{$data[$i]{$_}//"NaN"}@c}}' input
```

Comment: Impressive stuff! I like it :)